# ask the user its name

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement, while-loop

I just started learning javascript and after learning loops and if else i wanted to write a small program that's asked the user its name and it is empty or its a number it will keep asking the user until it's a valid name. First if i write a string it will write to html but when program trying to run the loop it will fail to write the valid name.

```js
var getName = prompt("What is your name? ");


if (getName === null || !isNaN(getName)){

    while (getName !== null || isNaN(getName)){
        alert("Invalid name, please try again");
        getName = prompt("What is your name ? ");
       if (getName !== null || isNaN(getName)){
           document.write("Hello ", getName);
       }
    }
}else {
    document.write("Hello ", getName);
}
```

Why my code does not work after getting into loop and after entering a valid thing program still says "it's not a valid name try again"?

Comment: it does not work after not entering a valid name. it got stuck at invalid name loop

Comment: Your while loop is using the wrong condition. You DON'T want it to continue if you have a valid name. Try `!(getName !== null || isNaN(getName))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the condition `getName === null || !isNaN(getName)` instead, check the following example.

Hope this helps.

```js
var getName = null;

while (getName === null || !isNaN(getName)){
  getName = prompt("What is your name ? ");

  if (getName === null || !isNaN(getName)){
    alert("Invalid name, please try again");
  }else{
    document.write("Hello ", getName);
  }
}
```

Comment: i did something likes this at first but i messed up that too. its works. this is really disappointing for me. i should read more... anyway thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
var getName = prompt("What is your name ? ");


if (getName === null || !isNaN(getName)){
    while (getName !== null || isNaN(getName)){
        alert("Invalid name, please try again");
        getName = prompt("What is your name ? ");
        console.log(getName)
       if (getName !== null || !isNaN(getName)){
           document.write("Hello ", getName);
           break;
       }
    }
}else {
    document.write("Hello ", getName);
}
```

Here is the [JSFiddleLink](https://jsfiddle.net/yfo975p2/)

Answer (score 0):

```
while (getName !== null || isNaN(getName)){
  alert("Invalid name, please try again");
  getName = prompt("What is your name ? ");
  if (getName !== null || isNaN(getName)){
     document.write("Hello ", getName);
  }
}
```

Let's compare the conditions for your while loop and for your if statement, notice how they are exactly the same.

Let's say the conditions evaluates to true, so what you have is

```
while(true) {
  // do something
  if (true){
     // do something
  }
}
```

So, the loop runs, and if statement executes, but you did not do anything to exit the loop.

In this case, you want your while loop condition to be true while the if statement is false, and vise versa, so do

```
while(!(getName !== null || isNaN(getName)))
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be what you're looking for but here is recursive function to do what you are looking for. Little bit cleaner easier logic.

```js
function ask(){

name = prompt("What is your name?");
  
    if(name != null && isNaN(name) & name != ""){
       document.write("Hello ", name);
    }else{
      alert("Invalid name, please try again")
      ask();
    }
}

ask();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>test</title>
 <script type="text/javascript " src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>



</body>
</html>
```